# Will anything happen with my Github repository if I move a local folder anywhere in Local Disk D in which .git is located?

Tags: windows, github, directory

I want to rename and move a folder named "Java Complete" (in this folder I have ".git" and Java Project named "Java-Essentials") from Local Disk C to Local Disk D. It is linked with my Github Repository. I want to ask that will anything happen with Github Repository? if I change the folder location and, if not then, can I commit files to that repository in the same way, or does it affect contribution on Github. I am new to Github ;)

I am expecting that it will not affect the repository and I can still contribute to it.

Comment: I found the solution, whenever you want to move the folder in which .git is located. Just initialize it again by using "git init" command and you are ready to go.

Comment: You should put that comment in an answer, and "accept" it. This won't get you any "reputation points", but it will help others. FWIW,  your Q was the first item that appeared in my search window.